# Convert Linq code from VB.Net to C# (Group Join)

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have to convert the following expression from VB.NET to C#:

```
            Dim query = (From egyosztaly As UpdateItemBase In UpdateItemCollectionRemote
                     Group Join egystudent As UpdateItemBase In UpdateItemCollectionLocal On egyosztaly.HashCode Equals egystudent.HashCode
                     Into csoport = Group
                     From egycsoportelem In csoport.DefaultIfEmpty
                     Select New ComparedUpdateItem With {.Remote = egyosztaly, .Local = egycsoportelem}).ToList()
```

My attempt:

```
            var query = (from egyosztaly in UpdateItemCollectionRemote
                     join egystudent in UpdateItemCollectionLocal on egyosztaly.HashCode equals egystudent.HashCode into csoport
                     from egycsoportelem in csoport.DefaultIfEmpty
                     select new ComparedUpdateItem() { Remote = egyosztaly, Local = egycsoportelem }).ToList();
```

The second "from" part is not understandable by C#.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Have you compared the results in Linqpad?

Comment: I think you need to add braces to your second last line: `from egycsoportelem in csoport.DefaultIfEmpty()`

Comment: Is query syntax mandatory?

Comment: Yes, the () is missing. Now its ok! Can somebody tell my why the question downvoted (good to know for the future)?

Answer (score 2):

In C# you need to be explicit when you call a method with no arguments, to provide empty parentheses. Identifiers without parens are usually considered properties, not methods (functions in vb nomenclature)

```
var query = (
    from egyosztaly in UpdateItemCollectionRemote
    join egystudent in UpdateItemCollectionLocal on egyosztaly.HashCode equals egystudent.HashCode into csoport
    from egycsoportelem in csoport.DefaultIfEmpty() 
    select new ComparedUpdateItem() { 
      Remote = egyosztaly, 
      Local = egycsoportelem 
    }
  ).ToList();
```

`DefaultIfEmpty` is a method and you want to call it, so you need to add `()`

---

In VB developers often don't really care about the same set of things we care about in C#; in C# we care quite a lot about things like naming and case sens:

```
class SomeName{                                    //class names PascalCase
  private int _someInt;                            //private vars camelCase, usually underscore led
  public int SomeInt { get { return _someInt; } }  //public properties PascalCase

  public void SomeMethod(int someArgument){        //methods PascalCase, arguments camelCase
    void localFunction() { ... };                  //local function, usually camelCase
    int localVariable = 0;                         //local vars camelCase

    SomeStaticClass.SomeMethodWithNoArgs();        //Static classes PascalCase, method calls with no args must include ()
    someInstance.SomeMethod(1);                    

    var x = new Thing { X = 1 };                   //new calling default constructor no longer requires () if initializing properties
    Thing x = new();                               //but does if new stands alone   
  }
}
```

Ultimately, it's usually possible to look at some code and know what is going on just from the casing; the only time it gets hazy is in scenarios like this:

```
AddAction(Foo.SomeThing)  //AddAction is a method that takes.. er..
```

`Foo.SomeThing` here could be a property of an instance called Foo or it could be a method of a type called Foo - when we're calling a method that takes *a method* (a delegate) as a parameter we pass the method name without the `()` - putting `()` would call the method and pass the result

```
AddAction(Foo.SomeThing)   //SomeThing could be a property or a method
AddAction(Foo.SomeThing()) //SomeThing is a method, called and its return value passed to AddAction
```

In latest VS properties and methods are colored differently which helps with this case. For a use case where you have "a method that takes a method", you'll come across that quite a lot in LINQ, but I'll give an example using List:

```
var strings = new List<string>() {"hello","world"};

strings.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

ForEach is a method that takes a method argument. List will loop over itself calling the supplied method once for every item. The method that is passed must accept a string as an argument, like Console.WriteLine does. All the strings in the list will print to the console. It's legal to pass the method name without the `()` because we don't want to call the WriteLine method and pass the result to ForEach (actually WriteLine has no result); we want to pass the *WriteLine method itself* to ForEach

Similarly this syntax "creates a mini method":

```
x => something_here;
```

So this is legal too:

```
strings.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x.ToUpper()));
```

The whole `x => Console.WriteLine(x.ToUpper())` thing is "a method that takes a parameter called x, of type that will be deduced from ForEach's signature which for a list of strings is 'a method that takes a single string argument'". In VB the equivalent is:

```
strings.ForEach(Function(x) Console.WriteLine(x.ToUpper));
```

(And of course VB wouldnt care if if was `ToUpper` or `ToUpper()` but C# people care quite a bit about these detils because it's vital to help understand a program and get clues as to what is what) :)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! Now the syntax is ok, I can check the result after I translate every part of code, but I think it will be good.